# My closed popup opens when I go out of the function

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, auto-update, testcomplete

firefox throws a pop up 'an update is available' whenever I open the browser. So I used a code to close the popup after launching in my 'open_browser' function.

```
if (Sys.Browser("firefox").Window("MozillaWindowClass", "", 8).Exists) {
Sys.Browser("firefox").Window("MozillaWindowClass", "", 8).Close();
```

But for time being it is closed. when I come out of that particular function to the main program, the pop up opens again. can someone help?

[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRRSE.png)

Comment: Why don't you update your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following URL for disabling the automatic updates and it'll no longer show you any pop-up to update

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/general/preparing-browsers/firefox.html